# Angular library does not install properly with NPM

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code

I just installed the following library via NPM

```
npm install -g ngx-gallery --save
```

https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery

So in VS Code, how come the import statement in my app.module.ts still has a squiggly red line?

[image]

Comment: Did you install it while VS Code was open? Have you tried closing/re-opening VS Code? Sometimes it does not recognize things installed after the folder is opened.

Comment: Also, check in `node_modules` folder if the `ngx-gallery` module actually exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your package.json for the dependency. Here you can add scripts and styles of 3rd party providers. Please have a look and see if ngx-gallery is included.

[image]

Can you also check your node modules to see if the package is there, if so you can give the full path in the import.

Here is a [link](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages) to the Angular documentation on dependencies

Comment: Its there, I just restarted it. I'm more used to Visual Studio where I've never seen quite this behavior.